# Solving simple decision-making model over multiple periods

Tags: optimization, markov-process, control-theory, decision-theory

Consider the following model.

Each period t=0,1,..., an agent makes an effort $x\in R_+$ to solve a problem. The value from solving the problem is $V>0$. The relationship between effort and problem solving is stochastic. So for any effort $x$ the probability of solving the problem is $p(x)$ (which is strictly increasing in $x$). And there is a cost associated with effort $c(x)$ (which is a quadratic function increasing in $x$). If the effort fails in one period, the agent can try anew in the next period (effort in one period does not affect the probability of success in the next). However, there is a discount factor $\delta\in(0,1)$ such that the agent may prefer to solve the problem now to solve it later.

If so, the decision problem at each period $t$ would be:
$$ \max_{x_t \in R} U = p(x) \cdot V - c(x) + (1-p(x))\cdot \delta \cdot U $$

where $U$ denotes the present value of the future payoffs of the agent.

What the agent should do to solve this problem optimally?

Comment: Can you solve problem several times, or just once?

Comment: Nope. Once the problem is solved, you earn $V$ and that's it. But you can attempt multiple times.

Comment: currently it seems that you have Bellman equation for the case where you can try solving the problem, and getting rewarded, as much as you want. More crucially, is the cost discounted as well? Anyways, it seems that the best solution is to maximize $p(x) V - c(x)$ as your decisions do not affect the future dynamics.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add the cost to the objective function. I am not sure about what you are suggesting as a solution. That would not take into account that solving the problem earlier is better than solving the problem later, i.e., for a discount factor $\delta<1$

Comment: I modified the objective function accordingly. No no discount on costs.